# Spring Integration Message Channel - Memory Based or File Based

Tags: spring-integration

I want to evaluate whether spring integration suits our current requirement or not.

We will receive an input stream which contains 1 million transactions (Let us Consider A in the below code is one transaction. One transaction size will be 4KB).

```
<A>

</A>

<A>

</A>

....

<A>

</A>
```

We will split the transaction into multiple records ( ) based on some conditions.

We will aggregate each group and push the same to another system.

**Could you please help me to understand the following?**

1. The entire process is memory-based or do we have the option to store it in the file? We are planning to run in K8S. The maximum size of a container is 1GB. We are expecting at least 20 transactions per minute. I am worried if we use in-memory operations, we will end up with performance or service outage problems.
2. Is it mandatory to use an aggregator? Because we are going to use the filter to segregate the files.
3. If I use the queue message channel, no two transactions will utilize the same queue object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregator is really not mandatory for your use-case. Even if you would use a persistent `MessageGroupStore` for the aggregator, in the end when you release a group you would load all the message back to the memory.

Yes, I think you have an option to collect the result data into a single file. See `FileWritingMessageHandler` with a `FileExistsMode.APPEND`. So, all your splitter record would be written to the same file in the end of flow. I think you even can come up with a strategy for the aggregator to write released group to the file as a single reply message.

I'm not sure in your question about a `QueueChannel`, but probably your assumption is wrong. It is just a channel between endpoints, and therefore all the messages sent to it are going to use same queue object. I would look into an `ExecutorChannel` instead to be able to process splitted data in parallel.